# How can I read input in JavaScript function line by line?

Tags: javascript

My JavaScript function accepts the input in this format:

```
6
12
```

How can I assign first and second line to variables?

Comment: What is the environment you are running in? Browser, node.js, etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have that input as a single string in a variable called `input`, you can use the [string `.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to create an array of lines:

```
var lines = input.split(/[\n\r]+/);   // ["6", "12"]
```

If you know there will always be two (or more) items, then you can get the first two from the resulting array:

```
var item1 = lines[0];   // "6"
var item2 = lines[1];   // "12"
```